# Android How to communicate from Wearable to Android handheld

Tags: android, wear-os

Hi I know how to send a notification from an android handheld device to my wearable device with a pending intent, (for a user action reply, and receive the response in a broadcast receiver) BUT! I am developing an android wear app that should be able to initiate the communication from the wearable to the android handheld device. The android handheld phone device has broadcast receivers that i would like to communicate with.

How would i do this? Send a Broadcast? send an intent? from my wearable.

Please help.

Comment: You have to use a WearableListenerService in your mobile app. From your wear app you can use a MessageApi